# Secondary axis excel chart (month/total)

Tags: excel, charts, axis, excel-charts, stacked-bar-chart

I have a question. I would like to display the costs incurred in a stacked Excel column chart. In addition, the columns should represent the monthly and annual cost types. However, the problem is that the annual values ​​need a different scaling, but unfortunately I can't find a solution to visualize the annual values ​​on a secondary axis. The wrong scaling can be seen in the screenshot. The only solution I know of would be to concatenate two charts. Is there any other solution? Thanks in advance.

|  | March 2022 | March 2021 | Year 2022 | Year 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cost1 | 14.230,00 € | 3.233,00 € | 566.652,00 € | 322.322,00 € |
| Cost2 | 12.131,00 € | 23.233,00 € | 652.656,00 € | 222.258,00 € |
| Cost3 | 2.323,00 € | 1.211,00 € | 233.232,00 € | 221.243,00 € |
| Cost4 | 4.543,00 € | 21.111,00 € | 122.223,00 € | 232.113,00 € |

[image: Screenshot wrong scaling chart]

Comment: Paste the numbers then people might test...

Comment: I add them. Do you have an idea?